# sheql expression for every Monday,Tuesday, and Friday

Tags: recurring-events, sheql

I just decided to represent recurring events using the notations in [this link](https://github.com/tusharmath/sheql/wiki/Rules).

But I could not figure out the sheql expression for every Monday,Tuesday, and Friday in a week. Can we represent it in a single expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible using the following query.

```
d!sun!wed!thr!sat
```